# How to pass an array by reference in assembly language?

Tags: assembly

I have 2 functions. One is call `CountChar` and `DisplayResult` as below. How am I going to pass the charInput array as reference from `CountChar` function to the `DisplayResult` function ? Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
CountChar PROC
    pushad

    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor edx, edx
    mov esi, 0
    mov ecx, bufSize
L1:
    mov al, buffer[esi]
    mov dl, charInput[eax]
    inc dl

    mov charInput[eax], dl          ; How to pass charInput as reference ????

    inc esi
    loop L1             ; end loop

        popad
        ret
CountChar ENDP



DisplayResult PROC
        pushad
        ; somehow retrieve the charInput from above for display ???
        popad
        ret
DisplayResult ENDP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer is a pointer is a pointer.  A pointer to data has the same number of bits as a pointer to code.  Those bits have no unique properties whether they are function vectors or data vectors.

You can do this a few ways ways

First,

DisplayResult PROC, the_vector:dword

```
mov    eax, the_vector    ; Moves the passed value "the_vector" into eax
call    eax
ret
```

DisplayResult  endp

or

DisplayResult PROC
    pop   edx    ; POP the return vector
    pop   eax    ; POP the function vector
    push  edx    ; Save the return vector for the 'ret' that will be done by [eax]
    jmp   eax    ; Jump to eax which will return to whoever called us
DisplayResult  endp

Get rid of all the pushad/popad stuff, it wastes time.  Only push the registers required and try to only use the registers that are expected to be destroyed.

The point of assembly language is to take advantage of the minor stuff so that it helps you in the end; otherwise, use C.

The C prototype for DisplayResult should be something like this:

extern void DisplayResult( void *);

When you call it, cast the function name as as a void *.  Like this:

DisplayResult( (void*)my_function );